# Problema estructura de datos Java

Tags: java

Tengo que resolver este ejercicio en java:

he intentando de varias formas pero no se como hacer para saber cuantas veces se ha consultado un dato si tengo el siguiente array con las referencias

como haría para mostrar cuales posiciones del array he consultado y cuantas veces lo he hecho?
Esto es lo que llevo hecho intento almacenar las consultas en un array distinto pero no se como hacer mostrar después este array que contiene las busquedas.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {
    public  int choice;
    public  int options;
    public   int prueba;
    public  int cont = 0;
    
    public void Menu() {
    do{ 
    
       System.out.println("¡Bienvenido! ¿que quieres hacer?   1- Ver referencias "
   + " 2-  Consultar referencias  3- Salir");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   options =sc.nextInt();
       switch (options){
     case 1: 
     int[] contador = new int [20];
     contador[cont++] = choice;
     System.out.println("posicion");
     prueba =sc.nextInt();  
    
     System.out.println(contador[prueba]);
   
    break;
     case 2:
   int[] referencias={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19};
   System.out.println("Escriba el numero de referencia");
  
   choice = sc.nextInt();
   System.out.println(referencia[choice]);
     break;
     case 3:
     
     break;
     default:
        System.out.print("Error");
         break;
       }
  
   

    }while(options !=3);
}
}
```

Comment: Pon el código que llevas hasta el momento para poder ayudarte, ya que si la dejas así te van a cerrar la pregunta porque aquí no hacen tareas.

Comment: edite mi pregunta agregando el código que llevo si tienes una recomendación o idea lo agradecería muchísimo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probé tu código, el principal problema es la ubicación de los arrays que guardan las referencias y la frecuencia de visita a cada referencia, ambos deben estar fuera del bucle do-while.

Tu problema es que, si bien ***case 2*** puede trabajar con el array ***contador*** (lo debe inicializar primero), los cambios que haga no se mantienen en una llamada posterior al switch. Y es ***case 2*** quien debe manipular las visitas en ***contador***

El segundo punto: como mostrar las visitas a una referencia específica, es decir ***case 1***. Ya que los indices estan "alineados" referencia[i] corresponde a contador[i]

```
System.out.println("La película "+referencias[prueba]+" fue visitada "
                    +contador[prueba]+" veces");
```

En cuanto al último punto: la referencia más consultada ***case 3*** hay varias opciones un bucle **for** tiene sentido por que el array es pequeño. Recorre el array ***contador*** y busca el mayor.

Hice un método para llamar desde ***case 3*** pero puedes incluir la lógica directamente en ***case 3***

```
    private int verMasConsultada(int[] contador) {
        int mayor = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < contador.length ; i++)
            if(contador[mayor] < contador[i]) mayor = i;
        return mayor;
}
```

Otra opción es una variable que recuerde cual es el más visitado y se modifique, si corresponde, con cada visita (me gusta más).

Este es tú código con esas modificaciones

```
public class Array {
  public  int choice;
  public  int options;
  public  int prueba;
  public  int cont = 0; // 
  public void Menu() {
    int[] referencias={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19}; // referencias
    int[] contador = new int [20];  // frecuencias
    do{ 
        System.out.println("¡Bienvenido! ¿que quieres hacer? 1- Ver Frecuencias  2- Consultar Referencias  3- Salir");
        System.out.print("opcion: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        options =sc.nextInt();
        switch (options){
        case 1: 
            //contador[cont++] = choice;
            System.out.print("posicion ");
            prueba =sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("---> La película "+referencias[prueba]+" fue visitada "+contador[prueba]);
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.print("Escriba el numero de referencia ");
            choice = sc.nextInt();
            contador[choice] += 1; // suma 1 con cada visita
            System.out.println("----> La pelicula "+referencias[choice]);
            break;
        case 3:
            int mas = this.verMasConsultada(contador);
            //System.out.println( Arrays.toString(contador)); // Borrar es solo para pruebas
            System.out.println("La mas buscada fue "+referencias[mas]+" vista "+contador[mas]+" veces");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.print("Error");
            break;
        }
    }while(options !=3);
 }
 private int verMasConsultada(int[] contador) {
    int mayor = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < contador.length ; i++) {
        if(contador[mayor] < contador[i]) mayor = i;
    }
    return mayor;
 }
}
```

Comment: Eres un crack había intentando miles de cosas pero no lograba hacerlo, muchas gracias por tu aporte